# Conditional probability with the condition expressed as a partition

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I want to calculate the following probability:

$$ P(A|B) $$

And I know a partition of $B$, that is $D_1$, $D_2$, $D_3$, ...

How can I express the probability $P(A|B)$ in terms of the probabilities of the partition of $B$: $P(D_1)$, $P(D_2)$ ...

Comment: Recall the definition of conditional probability $P(A|B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ when $P(B)\neq 0$.  Your partition of $B$ induces a partition of $A\cap B$.

Comment: Hint: You can write $P(B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(B|D_i) P(D_i)$ for any set B in the sample space and partition $\{D_i\}$ for the sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @hardmath comment:

$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{\sum P(A \cap D_i)}{\sum P(D_i)} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: if $G$ is an event, then 
$P(G)$ $ =$ $\sum _ { i } P(G \cap D_{i} )  $ 
Use this fact and definition of conditional probability.